# Index for SQL query optimization

Tags: postgresql, indexing

My task is to create such index/es, which will optimize the given SQL query for dvdrental database, without touching the query itself:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT title, release_year FROM film f1
WHERE f1.rental_rate > (
    SELECT AVG(f2.rental_rate) FROM film f2
    WHERE f1.release_year = f2.release_year
);
```

Output:

```
Seq Scan on film f1  (cost=0.00..69079.00 rows=333 width=19) (actual time=5.272..164.779 rows=659 loops=1)
  Filter: (rental_rate > (SubPlan 1))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 341
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=69.00..69.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.164..0.164 rows=1 loops=1000)
          ->  Seq Scan on film f2  (cost=0.00..66.50 rows=1000 width=6) (actual time=0.000..0.083 rows=1000 loops=1000)
                Filter: ((f1.release_year)::integer = (release_year)::integer)
Planning Time: 2.987 ms
Execution Time: 164.865 ms
```

From that I can see, the only thing we can optimize is the sequential scan on film f1, because subplan 1 contains aggregate. I tried plenty of indexes on the column `rental_rate`, but none of them produce any improvement. If I specify `set enable_seqscan = off;`, performance only gets worse. Maybe I am missing something here, but how it can possibly be optimized using indexes then?
P.S. The structure of film table:

[image: dvdrental database film table structure]

It contains 1000 rows, the column `rental_rate` contains float values with only 3 distinct values: 0.99, 2.99, 4.99.

Comment: postgres is more likely not to use an index if the size of a table is so small because in that case seqscan is more efficient than index scan. Insert more records in the table and the index will be used

Comment: Yes, I think the same. But the task is to optimize the given query for the given table) No idea how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1000 nested queries for avg - for each record in the table (you can see at as `loops=1000` in the plan).

Extracting these queries to CTE and further joining will increase speed you query:

```
WITH avg_rates as (SELECT AVG(f.rental_rate) avg, f.release_year
                   FROM film f GROUP BY f.release_year)
SELECT title, f.release_year FROM film f
JOIN avg_rates a on a.release_year = f.release_year
WHERE f.rental_rate > a.avg
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any way to improve it without modifying? E.g. make planner replace the inner seq. scan by the index scan.